# Cocos2d-Swift : Playing Sound Crashed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

I used below code to play sound in Cocos2d-Swift, its crashed.

```
 OALSimpleAudio.sharedInstanceWithSources(32).playEffect("buttonUp_1.caf")
```

How to resolve crash in swift code(not ObjC) ?

Or

Is there any other way to play sound in cocos2d-swift using SimpleAudio engine ?

Crash LOG:

**OAL Error: -[OALSimpleAudio initWithSources:]: : Could not create OpenAL device
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: The crash can be anything what error are you getting?

Comment: @KRUKUSA, added crash log in question.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
   OALSimpleAudio.sharedInstance().playEffect("buttonUp_1.caf")
```